# Date formatter using a vlookup

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I'm looking to create a date formatter but i'm having some questions.

Here's an example :

30-janv-14
21-FEB-14
26-FEB-14
03-mars-14

My plan is to transform this text in a real date format such as 30/01/2014.

I've created this formula :

```
  =IF(ISTEXT(H46);DATE(20&RIGHT(H46; FIND("-";H46; (FIND("-";H46)))-1);
    VLOOKUP(MID(H46;FIND("-";H46)+1;FIND("-";H46;FIND("-";H46)+1)-
    FIND("-";H46)-1);$Y$57:$Z$68;2;FALSE);LEFT(H46;FIND("-";H46)-1));H46)
```

Basicelly i'm extracting the date using LEFT / MID / RIGHT and to convert the month into number i've created a table ($Y$57:$Z$68) like below to retrive a number :

janv 1
fev 2
...

I'm coming here because i would like to know if there is a better method to do that, and also to now if there is a possibility to avoid having to create a table (month / number) such as a inline table {"janv", "1"; ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: IT would be lot easier if you split this data into multiple columns and do find -replace / lookup to convert text months like jan, feb into numeric like 1, 2. etc. And, finally use Date function with Left, Mid and Right functions to convert to Date format.

Comment: The goal is to make it automatic and avoid creating 5 column to do that.

Comment: Yes, You can make even this as automatic. Try recorded macro to do this cleaning stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2013 a cell containing '30-jan-14' will change to a proper date if you simply change the format of the cell from General (or text) to Date. I'm quite sure this happened prior to 2013 as well.